# Execute command just one time in a recursive function - Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a screen that needs to check all the time a condition (consider as a sensor signal or something) that changes its status all the time.

But I need to execute a command just when sensor goes True or goes False, just one time.

Take a look at the code and see that when the "condition" goes True, must "Execute command" just one time, and goes False, must "Execute another command" just one time. The problem is that always execute some command.

This command refers to a data base register.

```py
# Import libraries
import tkinter
import time

def screen():
    def screen_calc():
        """
            Screen_calc
        """
        screen_height_f = root.winfo_screenheight()
        screen_width_f = root.winfo_screenwidth()

        app_width_f = 1200
        app_height_f = 600

        app_x_f = (screen_width_f // 2) - (app_width_f // 2)
        app_y_f = (screen_height_f // 2) - (app_height_f // 2)
        return app_width_f, app_height_f, app_x_f, app_y_f

    def clock_update():
        """
            Clock update
        """
        clock.set(time.ctime())
        root.after(500, clock_update)
       
    def checkinput():
        if **"condition":**
            **"Execute command"**
        else:
            **"Execute another command"**
        root.after(500,checkinput)

    # Define Tkinter instance
    root = tkinter.Tk()

    # Define screen title
    root.title('__DKZ Watch Tower__')

    # Define screen geometry
    app_width, app_height, app_x, app_y = screen_calc()
    root.geometry(f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{app_x}+{app_y}')

    # Clock Update
    clock = tkinter.StringVar()
    clock.set(time.ctime())
    root.after(1000, clock_update)
    clock_label = tkinter.Label(root, textvariable=clock, relief='groove', width=app_width)
    clock_label.pack()
   
    root.after(500, checkinput)
    # Define application main loop
    root.mainloop()

screen()
```

I've tried to put a logic outside, calling the screen and other things but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need the equivalent of a state machine which remembers was has just happened. So if it remembers that the condition is already `True`, then it need not check again.

You can do it like this with a variable which remembers the state:

```py
    state = True      # Set this to which ever makes sense when the program starts
    def checkinput():
        nonlocal state
        if state:
            if not condition:
                print('Detect False')
                # **"Execute another command"**
        else:
            if condition:
                print('Detect True')
                # **"Execute command"**
        state = condition

        root.after(500,checkinput)
```

Comment: Awesome!!! The key was the 'nonlocal' word I did not knew. Has done perfectly! Thank you so much!!!!!

Comment: I've accepted and save the answer.  Thanks again.

Comment: Also an up-vote would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried but receive the information that I don´t have reputation enought to do this, but my feedback will be considered. I don´t know if I´m doing right but I tried in the arrow in left side of your answer.